# Samsung headphones' microphone not recognised on Macbook Pro

Tags: sound, headset

I have those headphones provided with most Samsung phones. I wanted to use the microphone that is on these headphones, but when plugged in, only the output device is displayed in the "Sounds" preferences or in `alsamixer`.

Is there anything I can do to have this microphone working?

Thanks a lot for your help!

P.S.: I can't think of any more detail to provide you with about this problem, feel free to ask me to execute some commands and post the result, maybe some sound-related `lspci` or something?

Answer (score 1):

The important part here is where you are plugging the headset into?

If you plug a 4-pin CTIA headset into a laptops' headphone jack and there is another microphone jack next to it then this is usually not going to work, you need an adapter in that case.

Newer laptops have *only one* CTIA compatible headphone jack where these headsets work fine and you would need an adapter that does the whole thing in reverse (splits the combined microphone jack into a dedicated headphone and dedicated microphone jack).

[image]

---

- [Debugging Sound Problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems)
- LP #1410618: [MacBook Air 6,2 TRRS Headset Mic Not Working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1410618)
- [Headset jacks on newer laptops](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2014/03/07/headset-jacks-on-newer-laptops/) by David Henningsson and [related section in the Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Sound#Handling_unknown_audio_jack_devices)

Comment: The headphones I have have the 4-pin pattern and my computer (a Macbook Pro, for reference) only has one jack. I already used these headphones on Mac OS and they were working just fine. I'm quite sure the solution is easy but I can't figure it out.. :(

Comment: @RichouHunter You could have mentioned that you use a Macbook Pro and the exact model earlier. I updated my answer with all that I know or could find.